# Angular 2 - Remember the expanded/collapsed state of accordion when switching tabs in app

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular2 app with seeveral tabs. One of the tabs has an accordion.

Accordion code in one of the tabs look like:

```
<accordion-group #somegroup panelClass="some-class">
    <div accordion-heading class="header">
        <span>Some text</span>
        <span class="chevron glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': somegroup?.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !somegroup?.isOpen}"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 body">
        ....
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

I can click on the icon to expand and collapse, so that perfects perfect.

Now, I want to store the expanded/collapsed state of accordion. So, if I expand this accordion, visit another tab and then come back to this tab, the expanded state should be remembered and accordion should be expanded by default. If it was collapsed when the tab was previously left, then coming back to this tab should have the accordion collapsed. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Note: The tabs are all different routes.

Comment: are your "tabs" actually routes? did you write the accordion yourself? Is this a library? Not nearly enough detail

Comment: yes, tabs are all different routes. I believe accordion-group is from the library

Comment: then you need to store the information in a service and retrieve it when the component loads and use whatever api the accordion library exposes to set the right one as open

Comment: I am able to store and retrieve the value from service. I am not very clear about how this accordion-group can be made to automatically keep expanded when tab is opened. I am using AccordionModule from g2-bootstrap/accordion.

Comment: literally the first line of the ng-bootstrap accordion docs examples shows this using activeIds parameter: <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">